# How to finish implicit class

Tags: scala

I am trying to write an implicit class that adds days to a date.

I know that I need two implicit classes. One for LocalDate and one for int.

However, I am stuck on how to finish these methods.

```
implicit class RichLocalDate(d:LocalDate) {
  def +(day: LocalDate):Path = ???
}

implicit class RichInt(n:Int){
  def jan():LocalDate = LocalDate.of(2016,1,n)

  def feb():LocalDate = LocalDate.of(2016,2,n)

  def mar():LocalDate = LocalDate.of(2016,3,n)
  ....
  ???
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample:

```
object Pimpeds {
  implicit class PimpedLocalDate[LocalDate](date: LocalDate) {
    def +(days: Int) = date.plusDays(days)
  }
}
```

When you need it:

```
import Pimpeds._

val myDate: LocalDate = ...
myDate.+(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to add two `LocalDate`s in the first place (i.e. your `def +(day: LocalDate):Path` method). What do you *want* to be the result of January 1st 2016 + January 1st 2016: February 2nd 4032? You most likely want `+(amount: TemporalAmount)` instead (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAmount.html), which just needs to call [`plus`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#plus-java.time.temporal.TemporalAmount-) method.